# Jane's sister in London

Tags: meaning, restrictive-clauses, postmodification

a. Jane talked to her sister in London on the phone.

b. Jane and her sister in London agreed about when to meet.

c. Jane's sister in London is a nice person.

Do these imply that Jane has more than one sister?

In other words, does "in London" modify the preceding noun restrictively?

======================

d. Tom was talking to his employees dressed in three-piece suits.

e. Tom and his employees dressed in three-piece suits paid me a visit yesterday.

f. Tom's employees dressed in three-piece suits were a little rude to me.

Do these imply that Tom has employees not dressed in three-piece suits?

In other words, does "dressed in three-piece suits" modify the preceding noun restrictively?

Comment: No to both questions. Jane could have sisters in other places than London; Tom could have employees dressed other than in three-piece suits.

Comment: By conventional standards of restrictive clauses, yes. It would be thought that she only has once sister. However, not everybody believes a lack of a comma necessitates a restrictive clause. That's a common style, but not a universal rule. (I will add that several of those sentences are unusually constructed, if not what many would consider incorrectly constructed, and probably not the best examples.)

Comment: Thank you both so much. This is interesting. I asked if they implied that she had more than one sister, and both of you said that she might have more than one sister. To me restrictive  clauses mean that we are selecting from a group. I think you're both native speakers, which means that the question should probably not be asked! My apologies.